# Request JS Uri requesting incorrectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to POST to a server using Request JS. I am having issues with parts of the path.

```
return await request.get({
      method: 'POST',
      uri: `${domain}/info/test/`,
      body: bodyAsString,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }).pipe(res);
```

This api has two ways to hit it: `/info/test` as a POST and `/info/test/:GUID` as a GET. For some reason, when I hit the API with Request it complains that 'test' is not a valid GUID like I am one level too low on the path. I can hit it in Postman just fine.

Comment: Is `${domain}/info/stream/` actually `${domain}/info/test/`? If so I'm guessing it's the `/` at the end that makes it expect a GUID.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I changed it at the last second before posting and missed one place. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use request.post instead of request.get

Comment: Yep, that did it. Clearly.